# Cannot read event log due to SecurityException

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, registry

I'm writing a little dll for my webapp. I'm monitoring a service i have a webpage that shows if a service is running, stopped or something other. So i'd like to get last 10 entries of EventLog logged by this service. But when i'm doing i get an exception while calling `ToArray()`. What should I do?

```
    public static IEnumerable<EventLogEntry> GetEventLogs(string serviceName)
    {
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(serviceName))
            throw new ArgumentException("Service not found", "serviceName");
        var myLog = new EventLog { Source = "MySource" };

        var entries = myLog.Entries;
        return (from EventLogEntry entry in entries
                where entry.Source == serviceName
                select entry).ToArray();
    }
```

So `EventLog.SourceExists(serviceName)` returns `true`, but after it fails.

It fails while iterating through `Security` folder, but i need `Application` only

---

---

**Solved**

It's funny that i can read from specified folder, however. It depends on `Log` property of `EventLog` class. So i should simple replace one row by this

```
var myLog = new EventLog {Source = "MySource", Log = "Application"};
```

Another joke is it works sometimes. And sometimes doesn't. For example this code works for my services, but fails with `netprofm` service.
tnx for help everybody

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have admin privileges to read from the Event Log. Are you running as the administrator?

You can also modify the permissions to this in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Security
```

Right click on that entry, select permissions, and make sure you have access.

You can't just skip the Security folder and look in Application only. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s7642se.aspx):

> To search for an event source in Windows Vista and later or Windows Server 2003, you must have administrative privileges. The reason for this requirement is that **all event logs, including security, must be searched** to determine whether the event source is unique. Starting with Windows Vista, users do not have permission to access the security log; therefore, a SecurityException is thrown.

[Further reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entries.aspx) and another relevant quote:

> It is not necessary to specify a Source when only reading from a log. **You can specify only the Log name and MachineName** (server computer name) properties for the EventLog instance.

Comment: I can run as admin, but on client side i won't. Can i programmicaly elevate privileges, perhaps using manifest and so on? And also problem is that i'm writing a dll, so calling code should also be runned as admin...

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky Elevation is a possibility, it depends on what kind of application this is. If your DLL is in the GAC, you should be able to write to the event log through that as the GAC will have privileges to do so. That basically stems from a requirement that in order to do a GAC installation, you need to have admin privileges when you install your app to begin with. If the client is totally unable to do so, then there's no way around this AFAIK.

Comment: Added some info above